# React Native App quits in background mode

Tags: ios, react-native, background

Having:

React Native Application. Using react-native-ble-plx (with background mode on in Capabilities in XCode) established connection to bluetooth device(wrist) that sends packet every minute. During the night. That is working and tested in most cases app works as expected, but in 1 to 3 cases app just disappears after (looks like) random amount of time. For the same build it may be 10 mins or 5 hrs.

**Crashlytics** is on - no errors.

**Logs from XCode Device Logs**, show no crash.

**Js logs** from RN - just stop, without any logs from ComponentWillUnmount on any level (Component, App). One of the thoughts was (we are using fetch to send logs to Scalyr) that may be app disposed by ios because of uploading the logs? May it be?

**Questions**:

1. Any ideas why this may happen?
2. We are also plan to add microphone recording during the night, we will turn on **audio** flag in Capabilities. May it improve the situation?
3. I know about background fetch approach, but it doesn't work for this situation because of microphone have to read every second of the night, and packets are coming every minute, and ios can't guarantee any constant interval between app awaking. But may there be any other solutions?